# warning: incompatible pointer types [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] in C

Tags: c, pointers, implicit-conversion

Why do I get a warning here? How can I fix this?

```
memUnit * newUnit = (char*) freeUnit + sizeof(memUnit);
```

I want to allocate a new Unit after the old Unit in my Memory (basically DIY calloc()). All variables with the word Unit in it are all of the struct memUnit.

Everything works fine like this, but how do I fix the warning?

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post more of your code. What is `freeUnit`? Why do you cast it to `char *`? Trying to set a `memUnit *` from a `char *` _will_ [correctly] be flagged.

Comment: FreeUnit is from struct memUnit

Comment: Okay, you want: `memUnit *newUnit = freeUnit + 1;` or `memUnit *newUnit = &freeUnit[1];` That's the beauty of C pointer types. You do _not_ add the number of _bytes_ in the element. You add _indexes_ into the arrays/pointers. When you do that, the compiler will handle the size automatically. The [effective] code is: `memUnit *newUnit = (void *)((char *) freeUnit + sizeof(memUnit));`. But, `freeUnit + 1` is easier, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign a `char *` into a `memUnit *`.

Now, I don't know what `memUnit` is in this context, but if it's larger than a single-byte value, you're assigning a byte-aligned pointer into a (something larger)-aligned pointer, and the compiler has every reason to complain. I'm assuming that's the problem.

If `freeUnit` is declared as `memUnit *`, you don't need to cast the pointer type. Just use:

`memUnit *newUnit = freeUnit + 1;` or `memUnit *newUnit = &freeUnit[1];`

If `freeUnit` is some other type, particularly one with a different size/alignment, you're on dangerous ground!

If it's a type with the *exact* same size as `memUnit`, and you have checked it's correctly aligned, you could cast it to `memUnit *` and add one, as above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion from a pointer to the type char * to any other pointer to object type except the type void *.

So you need to write either

```
memUnit * newUnit = ( memUnit * )( (char*) freeUnit + sizeof(memUnit) );
```

or

```
memUnit * newUnit = ( void * )( (char*) freeUnit + sizeof(memUnit) );
```